# Определить является ли число элементом последовательности Фибоначчи

Tags: python, python-3.x, лямбда-выражение, числа-фибоначчи

Нужно определить является ли число элементом фибоначчи с помощью лямбды, True/False.

Есть код `fib = lambda n, a=1, b=2: int(((a + 5**0.5)**n - (b - 5**0.5)**n) / (b**n * 5**0.5))` Который лишь выводит элемент.

Аналогично и тут, однако не уверен, что распаковку типа `a, b = b, a + b` в анонимных функциях возможно сделать.

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for __ in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
        if n == b:
          return True
    return False
print(fib(144))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одно из свойств [числа Фибоначчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%E8%F1%EB%E0_%D4%E8%E1%EE%ED%E0%F7%F7%E8):

> Натуральное число N является числом Фибоначчи тогда и только тогда, когда 5N^2 + 4 или 5N^2 - 4 является квадратом. Квадратное число — число, являющееся квадратом некоторого целого числа.

Таким образом получился такой немного громоздкий код:

```
from math import sqrt
fib = lambda n: True if sqrt(5*(n**2)-4)%1 == 0 or sqrt(5*(n**2)+4)%1 == 0 else False

fib(5) # True
fib(14) # False
fib(4181) # True
```

Что в нём происходит.

1. Вычисляем значения `sqrt(5*(n**2)-4)` и `sqrt(5*(n**2)+4)` и находим остаток от деления на 1. В случае, если одно из значений `(5*(n**2)-4)` или `(5*(n**2)+4)` является квадратом, то корень квадратный от такого числа является натуральным числом и, следовательно, остаток от деления на 1 будет равен 0.
2. Соответственно затем проверяем остаток от деления. Если один из остатков равен 0, выводим `True`, в противном случае -- `False`

Таким образом, при проверке не нужно каждый раз вычислять ряд Фибоначчи.

Comment: `fib = lambda n: sqrt(5*(n**2)-4)%1 == 0 or sqrt(5*(n**2)+4)%1 == 0`

Answer (score 2):

Вот такая функция получается:

```
is_fibo = ( lambda a: lambda v,fib=0,n=1: a(a,v,fib,n) )( lambda f,value,fib,n: f(f,value,fib+n,fib) if fib < value else fib==value )

>>> is_fibo(7)
False
>>> is_fibo(8)
True
```

1. Первая слева `lambda` определяет функцию с одним параметром `a`, который является функцией
2. Вторая слева `lambda` имеет 3 параметра, из них 2 необязательных, и состоит из рекурсивного вызова первой `lambda`
3. Эта конструкция исполняется и в качестве параметров получает третью `lambda` функцию, которая непосредственно занимается вычислением чисел Фибоначчи и сравнением с заданным значением.
4. При исполнении полученной функции все аргументы, кроме `value`, уже  определены. Вот `value` мы и задаём при вызове `is_fibo(..)`
5. Далее рекурсивно вычисляем числа Фибоначчи, пока очередное число не станет больше или равно нашему аргументу `value`. После этого возвращаем результат сравнения числа Фибоначчи и аргумента