# Установить точность вещ. числа для определения числа Фибоначчи

Tags: python

Задание такое
Вам дается последовательность чисел. Для каждого числа определите, является ли оно числом Фибоначчи.
Первая строка содержит одно число N  – количество запросов. Следующие N строк содержат по одному целому числу. При этом соблюдаются следующие ограничения:

Размер каждого числа не превосходит 5000 цифр в десятичном представлении.

Wrong answer на 6 тесте. Может кто нибудь помочь, пожалуйста

```
import math

n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input())
    fib1 = ((5 * a * a - 4) ** 0.5) % 1. <= 0.1 * 10 ** (-100)
    fib2 = ((5 * a * a + 4) ** 0.5) % 1. <= 0.1 * 10 ** (-100)
    if fib1 or fib2:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Comment: Что-то я лично не понимаю, что вы проверяете этими неравенствами, при чём тут фибоначчи вообще. Или есть такая формула?

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, проблема в том, что в формуле есть sqrt. И  при проверке нужно уточнить точность. Не знаю, как
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/970873/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8

Comment: А, ну да, я нашёл уже тоже. А почему вы не с нулём сравниваете? И почему остаток от `%1.`, а не `%1`? Вроде в том  вопросе таких сложностей не было

Comment: Ну, между `math.sqrt` и `**0.5` вроде нет никакой разницы в результате, второе даже лучше - библиотеку не нужно подключать

Comment: гляньте [на этот отвтет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1262993/209304) на функцию `is_fib()`

Comment: @Dmitry
WA на 6 тесте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Очень хороший тест состоит в том, что N является числом Фибоначчи тогда и только тогда, когда 5 N^2 + 4 или 5N^2 – 4 - это квадратное число.
```

**во-первых**

полученное число можно разложить на простые множители - кол-во различных простых множителей должно быть чётным - это 100% без всякой потери точности определение квадрата

вопрос насколько быстро можно перебрать простые множители от 2 до sqrt(5N**2 + 4) при условии, что в числе 5000 цифр

**а во вторых**

сравнивать квадраты лучше так:

```
int((5 * a * a - 4) ** 0.5)) ** 2 == (5 * a * a - 4)
```

тут тоже будет однозначный ответ

а еще быстрее так:

```
value = 5 * a * a - 4
value_sqrt = math.sqrt(value)
res1 = value_sqrt * value_sqrt == value
```

по возможности функцию возведения в степень лучше не использовать - она медленнее обычного умножения

**в-третьих**

для ускорения (если провал теста из-за скорости) лучше не вычислять сразу условия и для `5N+4` и для `5N-4`, а сделать последовательно, тогда на числах можно иногда экономить в 2 раза по скорости

```
value = 5 * a * a - 4
value_sqrt = math.sqrt(value)
if value_sqrt * value_sqrt == value:
    print("Yes")
    continue

value = 5 * a * a + 4
value_sqrt = math.sqrt(value)
if value_sqrt * value_sqrt == value:
    print("Yes")
    continue
```

Comment: Получаю Time Limit на 11 тесте. Вычисляю последовательно

Comment: да, проверил - проблема в том, что int во float не хочет преобразовываться `OverflowError: int too large to convert to float`